# Vue Stripe Checkout, issue with demo code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github, stripe-payments, element

I am trying to use and implement [Vue-Stripe-Checkout](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout), however I came across an issue in the very beginning with the demo code - at the very beginning when using the [Vue Stripe Elements](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout#vue-stripe-elements) from over here. I was wondering if someone knows what the issue is? It doesn't produce an error, but it simply doesn't work when the details are filled and the button is clicked.

The token function works, however the button click does not work, which is shown below

```html
<StripeElements
                :pk="publishableKey"
                :amount="amount"
                locale="auto"
                @token="tokenCreated"
                @loading="loading = $event"
                ref="elementsRef"
            >
            </StripeElements>
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="submit">Pay ${{amount / 100}}</v-btn>
```

```js
this.$refs.elementsRef.submit();
```

Sandbox Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-firefly-ovj4r?file=/src/App.vue

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console? can you share the html too?

Comment: @cjav_dev, updated. It's the same as the example code, nothing changed.

Comment: @Deathtitan77 Can you recreate this in a Vue CodeSandbox? eg: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-banach-wu7sg

Additionally, this appears to use the client-only approach to Checkout, which must first be enabled and configured: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client#enable-checkout

Comment: @NolanH Added to main post, I have enabled it however it still doesn't work. Would you be able to test from your end?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to supply your publishable key in `pk`: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-browser-qs7c4?file=/src/App.vue